# anchor title attribute

Tags: php

The title is showing only the first word when you mouse over the link. How can I get the whole order description to show? Thanks

```
<a title=$row[order_description] href=order.php?order_id=$row[qid]><font class=fontblueData_sub> $row[prod_title]</font></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double quote.

```
title="$row[order_description"

<?php
echo("<a title=\"" . $row[order_description] . "\" href=\"order.php?order_id=\"" . $row[qid] . "\">" . $row[prod_title] . "</a>")
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the attribute in quotes, like it's supposed to be.

```
<a title="..." ...
```

Comment: You can also use single quotes if using double quotes would require escaping.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, the code should look like:

```
<a title="<?= $row[order_description]; ?>" href="order.php?order_id=<?= $row[qid]; ?>">
   <font class="fontblueData_sub"><?= $row[prod_title]; ?></font>
</a>
```